# How to prevent | Mozilla FireFox (3.6) ContentEditable -- applies CSS to the editable container instead of it's content

Tags: firefox, styles, parent, block, contenteditable

I have some page with something like this:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">SomeText</div>
```

I have an selfmade JS editor which actually issues

```
document.execCommand(some_command,false,optional_value);
```

when user presses a button in the editor. (For example I have plain, simple [Bold] button).

Everything is fine as long as I apply editing to part of "SomeText". For example selecting "Text" with mouse and pressing [Bold] button (which leads to document.execCommand("bold",false,false);) will produce:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">Some<span style="some-css-here">Text</span></div>
```

but when I select entire content of the div ("SomeText" in this example) and press [Bold] in my editor, FF will not produce expected

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"><span style="some-css-here">SomeText</span></div>
```

but rather

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"  style="some-css-here">SomeText</div>
```

Notice the "style" attribute went into the editable div!

Why this makes a difference to me? 
--It's because after editing is done I would like to take the content of the editable div, along with all styles, formating etc and further use it on the page. But I can't -- all the styling now sits inside the div.
A solution when I would be advised to extract styles from the div is not acceptable -- the div during its life takes a lot of styles from other active elements of the page (heavy jQuery usage)

**So in brief:
How to tell FF to never touch editable div and apply all styling to its inner contents only?**

Sincere thanks for you time. 
(just pulled last of my hair, browsing FF dev site along with many others(((( )

Answer (score 2):

Call once before any other execCommand and switch FF to tag mode

```
document.execCommand('StyleWithCSS', false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes organizing and writing my thoughts brings me very  positive results.

I have found satisfactory solution.

1)insert hidden div as a first child node into your editing div:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
   <div class="edit_text_mozilla_hack"></div>
   SomeText
</div>
```

2) The CSS for it:

```
.edit_text_mozilla_hack {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    -moz-user-edit: none;
    -moz-user-select: none
}
```

3)Now you can edit. I tested it with this my small test (actually I need all this stuff to edit short pieces of text like like captions, news subjects etc)

4)Before you use the content -- obious -- remoe that div. 
5)When you want to return to editing -- insert it again.

Some bits of code from working (finally! ))) project:

```
//adds hidden div to all editable regions 'editables'
//the parameter is for speeding the thins up -- I'm often working with all or a lot of editable regions
function editAddMozillaHack(editables) {
    if (!editables) {
        editables = editGetEditables();
    }
    $("." + adminOptions["admin_loader"]).remove();
    editables.each(function() {
        $(this).prepend('<div class="edit_text_mozilla_hack"></div>')
    });
}

//removes the hack from all regions
function editRemoveMozillaHack() {
    $(".edit_text_mozilla_hack").remove();
}

//just returns all the editable regions -- my project often requires them all
function editGetEditables() {
    return $("[contenteditable=\"true\"]");
}
```

of course -- testing pending.
I would like to hear from you ;)
regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, when select all in contenteditable area with mouse or use CTRL-A there and then press CTRL+B for example, Firefox put style to the contenteditable container instead it's content.

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="font-weight: bold;"><p>..content..</p></div>
```

Same applyed for italic, font size, font-family and other inline styles.
I wrote a function which fixing that issue. It creates new element below the content and changes selected range till that element:

```
function checkSelectAll (container, cmd, args) {
    if(document.getSelection) {
        var     cn = container.childNodes,
            s = document.getSelection(),
            r = s.getRangeAt(0);

        if(r.startContainer == container && r.endContainer == container){
            var endMarker = document.createElement('SPAN')
            container.appendChild(endMarker);
            r.setEndBefore(endMarker);
            s.removeAllRanges();
            s.addRange(r);
            document.execCommand(cmd,false,args);
            container.removeChild(endMarker);

        } else {
            document.execCommand(cmd,false,args);
        }
    } else {
        document.execCommand(cmd,false,args);
    }
};
```

this code affects only FF, for other browsers it will just apply execCommand